# Trying to use the column created using dynamic value in where clause but getting error

Tags: sql-server

I have this column in the select

```
count(case when table1.col1 = 1 then 1 end) over(partition by table1.col3) as showID
```

I'm trying to use it in a `where` clause

```
like `showID > 0`
```

but I'm getting an error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 126
>   Invalid column name 'showID '

Comment: Please provide complete query here

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Your original dataset does not have `showID` column, only the dataset resulting from your `SELECT`. Filtering with `WHERE` only filters rows of the original data, if you want to filter after the `SELECT` use `HAVING` or write a sub-query.

Comment: @GMX that depends on your exact query -- please post it completely and we would be able to help you better

Answer (score 0):

WHERE will be executed prior to projection. So, showID will not be availble to sql engine at time of WHERE clause evolution.

Please refer the sequence [here](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations)

[image]

That said, if you could post your query, then we could help (probably to guess, use CTE/temp table and then join on that. )